# PowerBI does not run even simple python scripts

Tags: powerbi

it looks like my WinPython installation is recognized by PowerBI Desktop.

Still even simple scripts as this one from MS learn

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Product)
dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()
```

or

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
  
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
   
df
```

are complained with no visual created even if there is a

```
print(df)
```

which works even on the command line

is there something else needed ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a Python script visual or use a Python script purely within the query editor?

Comment: I dragged the python visual to the report and expected I could fill it with the python script